# $X_1, \dots, X_n$ are i.i.d random variables taking values in $\mathbb R$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

$X_1, \dots, X_n$ are i.i.d random variables taking values in $\mathbb R$, could anyone tell me what can I say about

$\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n} E(e^{tX_i})$?

Suppose $E(X_i)=\mu$ then $E(e^{t X_1})=E(\sum \frac{(tX_1)^n}{n!})$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since these random variables are independent, the product commutes with the expecatation:
$$\prod_{i=1}^n E(e^{tX_i}) = E\left(\prod_{i=1}^n e^{tX_i}\right).$$
By properties of the exponential, we can turn $e^{a_1}\cdots e^{a_n}$ into $e^{a_1+\cdots+a_n}$:
$$E\left(\prod_{i=1}^n e^{tX_i}\right) = E\left(e^{\sum_{i=1}^n tX_i} \right)=E\left(e^{t\sum_{i=1}^n X_i} \right).$$
So this is the moment generating function of $\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$.

Comment: does this has some compact form? If $E(X_i)=\mu\forall i$

Comment: What do you mean by "compact form"? It depends on the distributions of the $X_i$'s, not just their means. You can't get more specific than this without specifying the distribution of $X_i$.

Comment: I am confused, I don't think those $X_i$ are IID.

Comment: You initially defined $X_{i+1}$ as a function of of $X_i$, so the value of $X_{i+1}$ seems to depend on the value of $X_i$. Thus they are not independent. They probably also don't have the same distribution, unless these $f$'s preserve the distribution of the $X_i$'s.

Comment: You should post a new question. Nobody is going to come looking in the comments of a question with an accepted answer to help answer this.

Comment: I have asked here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3368075/probability-upper-bound-of-sum-of-random-variables